# Fetch attributes for specific keys using Jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have been trying to set key names for json array using the fields provided. I need to fetch a separate list of managers and colleagues.
Input:

```
{
  "employeelist": [
    {
      "employee": "test",
      "firstName": "ABC",
      "lastName": "DEF"
    },
    {
      "employee": "test1",
      "firstName": "nametest",
      "lastName": "namelast"
    }
  ],
  "manager": "test",
  "colleague": "test1"
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "manager": [
    {
      "employee": "test",
      "firstName": "ABC",
      "lastName": "DEF"
    }
  ],
  "colleague": [
    {
      "employee": "test1",
      "firstName": "nametest",
      "lastName": "namelast"
    }
  ]
}
```

Spec I used repeats the the complete list for both managers and colleagues.

```json
[
  { // segregate values of the same key and form respective arrays.
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "employeelist": {
        "*": {
          "employee": {
            "@(3,manager)": {
              "@2": "manager.[]"
            },
            "@(3,colleague)": {
              "@2": "colleague.[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "employeelist": {
        "*": {
          "@": "@1,employee" // accumulate values of "manager" and "colleague" attributes with respective "employee" values under the common arrays labeled by those values 
        }
      },
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)" // exchange the key-value pairs of the attributes "manager" and "colleague"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // all newly transformed arrays
        "@1,&[0]": "@(2,&[1])[]" //match values of 0th and 1st components per each array while adding a [] suffix to convert the resultant objects nested within square brackets as desired 
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where the first components(`[0]`) of the newly derived arrays(`test` and `test1`) are matched with the second components(`[1]`) within the last spec

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: is there some documentation around these kind of operations? I had went through the intercom docs on Jolt but was not able to conclude into solution like this.

Comment: @Scorpy Explanation for your last comment : Principally need to match [0](the first components) with [1](the second).
Since there are two components, for the arrays formed within the previous spec , per each common employee value.
Eg. [0] does not represent the first array but the first components of the each array. Btw, I'm converting the &1 to &
which is stated on the right hand side as doesn't differ as the level, but preventing confusion. Both would stand for 
the keys of the independent arrays (test and test1).

Answer (score 1):

I think this simpler jolt spec might achieve the expected output, but please note that it works only if the document that needs to be moved to the `"manager"` field is the first element of the array (that's why it matches the 0 index), and the document of `"colleague"` is the second element of the array (index 1).

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "employeelist": {
        "0": "manager[]",
        "1": "colleague[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Hope you find it useful!